# How to use Scrapy to find out the number of spans?

Tags: python, css, scrapy, css-selectors

How to use Scrapy to find out the number of spans?

```html
 <div class="filled">
   <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
   <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
   <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
   <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-full"></span>
   <span class="hg3-i hg3-i-star-half"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code in which you attempted to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(len(response.css('div.filled span')))
```

which means: select `span` tags that are inside `div` tag with `filled` class, get length of the selector list

[scrapy selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), [CSS selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scrapy response

```
spans= response.xpath('//div[@class="filled"]//span')
```

taking the the `len(spans)` returns the result